Can every $\ast$-algebra be represented in this space of matrices?
Let $k$ be a field with characteristic $0$. For every set $X$, let $\mathcal{B}(X)$ be the set of (possibly infinite) matrices $T = (T_{x,y})_{x,y \in X}$ with coefficients in $k$ such that in each line and in each column there are at most finitely many nonzero coefficients. The set $\mathcal{B}(X)$ has natural structure of $\ast$-algebra over the field $k$, with involution given by transposition and multiplication by usual matrix multiplication which is well-defined by the finiteness condition.
When $X$ is a finite set, we get the usual $\ast$-algebras of finite matrices.
A wide variety of $\ast$-algebras can be faithfully represented in $\mathcal{B}(X)$ for some set $X$. For example, given a group $G$, one can represent it on $\mathcal{B}(G)$ by defining
\begin{align*}
\lambda \colon G &\to \mathcal{B}(G)
\end{align*}
where $\lambda(g)$ is the matrix whose entries are $\lambda(g)_{x,y} = 1$ if $g = xy^{-1}$ and $0$ otherwise. One can check that $\lambda$ induces a faithful $\ast$-representation of $k[G]$ with involution given by $g \mapsto g^{-1}$ on $\mathcal{B}(G)$.
One can use the same strategy to represent Steinberg Algebras. It can shown that the category of $\ast$-algebras that can be represented in some $\mathcal{B}(X)$ has all limits and colimits.
Even more unusual algebras, such as $k$ with multiplication given by $a \cdot b = 0$ for every $a,b\in k$ and trivial involution, can be represented.
I have tried various examples of $\ast$-algebras, and so far, I have always found some faithful representation into those spaces.
Question: Can every $\ast$-algebra $A$ be represented in $\mathcal{B}(X)$ for some set $X$?

Edit: As commented by Prof Steinberg, the question is false for subfields of the real numbers. The case that I most care of is $k = \mathbb{Q}_p$ the field of the $p$-adic numbers. Is the question also false for this specific field?

How would you achieve such a representation if $k$ is the complex numbers and $A=B(\ell^2)$?

It is also not clear to me how one would represent group Cstar algebras of various non-amenable groups - I don't see a unified way to do it, but I admit I have not thought very hard.

@YemonChoi I thought about these big algebras such as $A = B(\ell^2)$ and $A = \overline{k}$ the algebraic closure (if $k$ is not already algebraically closed) these algebras are hard to represent, but maybe this is just because they are messy algebraically. I could not prove that there are not a representation in some big set $X$.

If k is a subfield of the reals doesnt your matrix algebra satisfy a*a=0 implies a=0, which is not satisfied by all *-algebras over k?

@BenjaminSteinberg Yes, you are right. The cases that really interest me are the non-archimedean fields and they do not satisfy this. But you are right, so this is not true in general.
